# JavaScript multi-dimensional array manipulation - creating children arrays from object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on an application that has user data. I've come back with the 5 favorite users - and I want to create arrays based on their properties.

jsfiddle
https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-beaver-ftj25j?file=/src/index.js

One person - will have key characteristics I wish to sample.
[image]

When I have collected the characteristics array from each - it forms a multi-dimensional array as follows.

[image]

I want to now go over this data -- and create an array for each property.

```
gender array - ["1", "2", "2"]
eyeColor array - ["3", null, "3"]
hairColor array - ["2", null, "2"]
build array - ["8", null, "8"]
ethnicOrigin array - ["9", null, "9"]
```

-- what is the best approach for this

That's where I've got up to - in terms of getting the characteristics from each person -- and then going over all of them to collect this multi-dimensional array

```
let needles = ["gender", "eyeColor", "hairColor", "build", "ethnicOrigin"];
let characteristics = [];

for (let i=0; i < this.state.users.people.length; ++i) {
  let personCharacteristics = []
  for (let j=0; j < needles.length; ++j) {
    personCharacteristics.push({ [needles[j]] : this.state.users.people[i].appearance[needles[j]] })  
  }

  console.log("==========personCharacteristics", personCharacteristics)
  characteristics.push(personCharacteristics);      
}

console.log("==========characteristics", characteristics)
```

You can see in "personCharacteristics" the array object looks like this

```
[
 {"gender":"2"},
 {"eyeColor":"2"},
 {"hairColor":"4"},
 {"build":"6"},
 {"ethnicOrigin":"6"},
]
```

code snippet

```js
let people = [
  {
    name: "Billy",
    appearance: {
      gender: "1",
      eyeColor: "2",
      hairColor: "4",
      build: "6",
      ethnicOrigin: "6"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Jason",
    appearance: {
      gender: "1",
      eyeColor: "1",
      hairColor: "1",
      build: "2",
      ethnicOrigin: "3"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Roger",
    appearance: {
      gender: "1",
      eyeColor: "3",
      hairColor: "6",
      build: "4",
      ethnicOrigin: "5"
    }
  }
];

let needles = ["gender", "eyeColor", "hairColor", "build", "ethnicOrigin"];
let characteristics = [];

for (let i = 0; i < people.length; ++i) {
  let personCharacteristics = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < needles.length; ++j) {
    personCharacteristics.push({
      [needles[j]]: people[i].appearance[needles[j]]
    });
  }

  console.log("==========personCharacteristics", personCharacteristics);
  characteristics.push(personCharacteristics);
}

console.log("==========characteristics", characteristics);
```

Comment: How does the last chunk of code relate to your question?

Comment: That's where I've got up to - in terms of getting the characteristics from each person -- and then going over all of them to collect this multi-dimensional array

Comment: Please post actual code not pictures of it (or in addition to it) so we might have a "source data" example to work with here.

Comment: I have posted the current code along with showcasing how the data looks

Comment: To echo @MarkSchultheiss comment, allow me to [point you to the FAQ about this on the meta site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) It's the *data* we're looking for. The code's great, but without knowing what the data is (because it's hidden in pictures), it's not as useful.

Comment: I've now written the array object for personCharacteristics to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is below, with explanatory comments in the JavaScript to make sense of the code:

```js
// the original data:
let people = [{
      name: "Billy",
      appearance: {
        gender: "1",
        eyeColor: "2",
        hairColor: "4",
        build: "6",
        ethnicOrigin: "6"
      }
    },
    {
      name: "Jason",
      appearance: {
        gender: "1",
        eyeColor: "1",
        hairColor: "1",
        build: "2",
        ethnicOrigin: "3"
      }
    },
    {
      name: "Roger",
      appearance: {
        gender: "1",
        eyeColor: "3",
        hairColor: "6",
        build: "4",
        ethnicOrigin: "5"
      }
    }
  ],
  // here we take the people Array of Objects, and use
  // Array.prototype.reduce() to create something new
  // from that original Array:
  appearanceAttributes = people.reduce(
    // Array.prototype.reduce() gives access to the
    // accumulator (the Object we're creating in this instance),
    // and the current Array-element of the Array over which
    // we're iterating; from that Array-element - itself an Object -
    // we use destructuring to assign the 'appearance' property
    // of the Object to the variable of the same name:
    (acc, {appearance}) => {
    
      // we retrieve the Object-entries, an Array of two-part
      // Arrays, comprising of a key value pair from the
      // appearance Object:
      let entries = Object.entries(appearance);

      // we use Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
      // resulting Array:
      entries.forEach(
        // again using destructuring assignment to assign the
        // first Array-element to the variable of 'key', and
        // the second element to the variable of 'value':
        ([key, value]) => {
          // if the accumulator Object ('acc') does not have
          // a property-name matching the current 'key':
          if (!acc[key]) {
            // we initialise that property of the Object to
            // an Array-literal:
            acc[key] = [];
          }
          // and then we push the value variable into the
          // Array:
          acc[key].push(value);
        });
      // returning the accumulator for the next iteration:
      return acc;
    // initialising the accumulator Object as an Object literal:
    }, {})

console.log(appearanceAttributes);
/*
{
  gender: ["1", "1", "1"],
  eyeColor: ["2", "1","3"],
  hairColor: ["4", "1", "6"],
  build: ["6", "2", "4"],
  ethnicOrigin: ["6", "3", "5"]
}

*/
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/03dftqbo/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- Literals:

  - [Array-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals).
  - [Object-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#object_literals).
- [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped!